# how to make htdocs folder accessible over internet

Tags: php, networking, wifi, hardware, configure

Hello Friends ,
                                                                                                                          I use to display my website by giving this link                            [http://myipaddress/www.abc.com] to my friends
        over internet Here i was using my broadband connection but now i purchase a router and i am 
        connecting my internet through it
        and now when i give the same link .They can't able to access my website..need help guy.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to portforward your Apache Port (typically 80 unless specified different

use: http://www.portforward.com

for information how to portforward with a router.

---

Access your router settings? If you do not know:

1. Open Command prompt
2. Issue ipconfig

You should be presented with:

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::d168:1665:65c:7c2e%12
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.2
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
```

Or something that looks like this.

1. Type your default gateway into your URL bar

Answer (score 0):

You need to forward the port "80" (or the port that is used by your http server), to the local machine serving it.

Answer (score 0):

Like Maresh said you need to forward the http port (80) in your router to the computer that's serving the website and also if you're using apache edit the httpd.conf file.

This is what mine looks like, I'm only allowing users on the local network

```
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/"
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride All

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
# Online --> Require all granted

#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove

Require local
#Require all granted

</Directory>
```

To allow wide area network, remove the # from '#Require all granted' and put it infront of 'Require local'.

The above code is only a section from the httpd.conf file but that's the section that you'll want to edit, search for 'Require local' in the editor to find it.